# Create reusable block of vue template within creating new component

Tags: html, templates, vue.js, dry, extends

In some instances, I need to just repeat some html code within my Template to DRY it up, but making a new component and passing a ton of props and dynamic data to it seems like overkill. Is there a way to define a repeatable block of template code that can just be reused?

A good example of this is my vuelidate validation `error` messages that are repeated. I don't want to create an entire vue component for them because then I need to pass in the validation, validation prop and a few other things so that seems like creating more complexity just to DRY up a little bit of the template.

I have this block of code on three different scenarious in the same template, is there a way I can just define them as a `block` to reuse. Literally nothing changes so it's very much against DRY principles.

```
<span
   v-if="!$v.initialReplyText.required"
   class="error">Your reply cannot be empty.</span>
<span
   v-if="!$v.initialReplyText.maxLength"
   class="error">Your reply cannot be over 2,000 characters.</span>
```

Comment: I am looking for this answer as well, but it seems like vue doesn't supports it.

Answer (score 1):

you can do dynamic binding using  `v-bind`, that way you don't need to bind all properties individually.

```html
<!-- pass down parent props in common with a child component -->
<child-component v-bind="$props"></child-component>
```

src: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind

You can also use slots, or scoped slots, which are commonly used for things like wrapping error messages in more complex markup.

Comment: is there any example showing how to use this $props? because i checked the document and its not having an example, only saying that  props should be common between the two component.

Comment: `$props` is an object made available in the template by Vue. you can type `{{$props}}` somewhere in your template to see the value. Seems your question is not related to the OP's question. You may want to create a new question with your details.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

If all elements are consecutively arranged as in your example, you can use v-for as below:

```
<span v-for="(criteria, msg) in {'Your reply cannot be empty.': !$v.initialReplyText.required, 'Your reply cannot be over 2,000 characters.': !$v.initialReplyText.maxLength }" 
      v-if="criteria" class="error">
    {{msg}}
</span>
```